# Travel Recommendations allowed on this stack?

Tags: discussion, scope

I do apologise for potentially asking two questions here, but I am looking for some travel advice for my upcoming trip to Norway (what to see on my specific route of travel). Is this allowed on this site? -- or is it more about Visa's and that kind of 'travel' stuff?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: what to see - subjective and off-topic. Too many possible answers.  How to get from A to B? Yes. What visa? Yes. What ticket options with a particular discount card - sure.  Basically anything objectively answerable that matches the [help] is fine.  If it's subjective/after recommendations or you just want to chat - join the [chat] and we'll be happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to learn what Travel.SE is about is to read our [help centre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). On the on-topic page it says:

> Travel Stack Exchange is for road warriors and seasoned travelers.. If you have a question about …
>
> - customs & border crossing, visas and other travel documents such as permits
> - accommodation: camping, hostels & backpackers, guesthouses, B&B's, hotels, renting a villa on a trip
> - loyalty programmes: frequent flyer points and hotel advantages
> - health and safety issues related to travel
> - modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport
> - finances: budgets, costs, foreign exchange
> - working while on the go (WWOOFing, volunteer travel etc) - not immigration or work visas, see below
>
> and it's not about …
>
> - **asking for the 'best' thing to do (or similarly subjective questioning)**. Everyone is different. Detail what stuff you like to do/see if you're going down that route, so that we can better help you. Subjective questions are VERY likely to get closed.
> - **asking to have your travel itinerary constructed**, including flight scheduling, budgeting and finding accommodation. Such questions cannot be answered as there are too many variables and personal preferences to account for, and are unlikely to be of use to others. An actual travel agent may be of assistance.
> - things that are overly broad or related to an overly big geographical region
> - cheapest [things, places] in [country, town, ...]
> - eliciting list-style answers, suggestions or recommendations on a topic or place (unless VERY specific criteria is listed)
> - a question where every answer is going to be equally valid (eg 'What country in Europe should I visit?' (which would also be overly vague and broad))
> - issues related to immigration / expatriates (see Expatriates Stack Exchange instead)
> - shopping suggestions

Unfortunately the question you are asking yourself now -- what to see on my specific route of travel? -- is both a travel-related question and is also off-topic on Travel.SE. The reason being that what to do is a subjective matter. What i like doing and seeing whilst travelling might not be what you like doing and seeing. Hence it would make no sense for us to answer such questions here since they would be of limited use for the next Traveller reading them looking for advice.

What I always suggest to new users is to look around the web for ideas, and them come on Travel to get top-notch advice by asking the on-topic questions they have. Also, I'd suggest you [come to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=travel.stackexchange.com) to discuss with fellow travellers. In chat we do not have off-topic rules per se so you are free to ask the passers-by if they've been to Norway and what they have done/seen.